# Is this "really" working as a tone-softener?

Tags: meaning-in-context

She never really accepts my idea.

Is this a weaker version of "she never accepts my idea?"

Comment: Yes, it works well in that role.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be the same as saying 'she never fully accepts my idea', implying that maybe she understands the main point of your idea but never accepts it in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a softer tone.  I would take out the word "never" because it can be a harsh word. You can also start with the phrase, "I feel that..."   This is the best way to soften tone, especially with family or work situations.  For example, I would say..."I feel that she doesn't except my ideas."  So, your sentence is the first level of softening tone.  Taking out "never" would be the next level, and the sentence I suggested would be the softest.  Using "I feel that" also helps the other person be more open to what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Example one: You e-mail Laura your ideas for a paper she is writing. She responds to your e-mails by saying "That's totally wrong." She doesn't change her paper at all. This happens over and over. You would say "She never accepts my ideas."

Example two: You e-mail Laura your ideas. She responds to your e-mails by saying "That's a good idea; let me think about it." Then she doesn't change the paper. Now it's appropriate to say "She never really accepts my ideas." (In other words, she pretends she is accepting your ideas, but never actually does.)

In conclusion, I don't really think it's weaker or softer. It implies that she is finding some indirect or sneaky way to reject your ideas, rather than rejecting them outright.